# Dropbox.Client returning authorization error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to authenticate my dropbox application using javascript. Now when i try to create a client using Dropbox.Client( dropBox_Credentials), I am getting an authorization error.

Now, the object "dropBox_Credentials" I am passing has my dropbox application key and secret. I verified it and they are correct. I have added the localhost uri to the dropbox application as well. I am completely stumped as to why this authorization error is returning null.I am using angularjs, requirejs and grunt, if that is in any way related.

Any help appreciated.

Please find below how I am passing the credentials object to the Client function.

```
var dropboxClientCredentials = {
  key: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

var dropboxClient = new Dropbox.Client(dropboxClientCredentials);
console.dir(dropboxClient);
```

Please find below the error I am getting. I am catching this error using angularjs failure callback.

**Failed: Dropbox OAuth error Authorization error :: null**

Comment: Do you want to use Dropbox datastore api?

Comment: Have you tried the normal client.authenticate with the provided error callback, as opposed to the angular stuff? E.g., try following the normal tutorial at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/js

Comment: Got it working. However had to generate a token manually from the dropbox app and then pass it in the sropbox.client method.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue a time ago. on my server.js I had something like this, to handle angularjs requests.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {   
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);  
});
```

With that dropbox's redirect( oauth step ), was sending me to my page, but on my console I was watching something like this

```
Failed: Dropbox OAuth error Authorization error :: null
```

If you change the code of your server.js to this

```
   app.get('*', function(req, res) {    
      res.sendfile( __dirname + "/public/index.html"); 
   });
```

You will be able to use dropbox's sdk without any issue.

I believe that this one isn't the best approach but you can save time until you find the best solution